# How can I repartition a windows drive without administrator access?

Tags: windows, administrator, storage

At my workplace we have a a computer with a hard drive divided into three partitions, the primary one is getting full and I'd like to give it some of the free space from the other two, the problem is that due to the age of the thing noone who works here knows the admin password anymore.

Is there an easy way for us to free up this space without admin access?

Comment: Create a gparted live USB, boot into it and make your changes from there.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Can you add additional information, such as the OS? There are major differences between Windows versions, so just saying you're using Windows is not enough. Thank you.

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini: Look at the tags.

Comment: @harrymc ... and look at the end of my comment. "Windows" is not an OS. "Windows XP", "Windows 7" and "Windows 10" are three different OSes.

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini: These differences don't matter, since the poster cannot use Windows Disk Management. For partition editing, Windows=NTFS, which is the only fact that matters.

Comment: @harrymc, not really. If the OS is Win7 and BIOS boots he could use the Offline PW Reset tool (by Pogostick). However, if it's Win8 or newer and UEFI boots he cannot. These details _do_ matter.

Answer (score 1):

You fully control any computer to which you have physical access.

Use a free partition editor that has bootable media, such as
[GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)
or
[AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html).

I suggest before modifying partitions, to take a backup image of the entire disk.
Don't use Windows Backup for that.

My favorite backup tool is
[AOMEI Backupper Standard](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).
As a precaution,  create the AOMEI bootable media and ensure it can boot
and see the disk where the backup image is stored,
before modifying any partitions.

Comment: Sometimes, the new partition size, although it could be resized with Linux, is not detected by Windows. See: the comments of my original post here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743676/kde-partition-manager-not-seeing-full-disk-size-after-cloning-windows-10-uefi